# log4j2 configuration of a secure TCP Socket appender in properties file format

Tags: sockets, security, tcp, log4j2, appender

I am trying to make my socket appender secure.
The current configuration is:

```
appender.socket.type = Socket

appender.socket.name = SOCKET_APPENDER

appender.socket.host = localhost

appender.socket.port = 4712

appender.socket.reconnectionDelayMillis = 10000
```

How do I add the SSL Config (Keystore config and truststore config) to it?

Comment: Is there some reason you need to use SSL when communicating with localhost?

Comment: @pvg - just did not feel like putting the ip address of the comapny's sytems here. So, replaced it with localhost.

Comment: simplest thing is probably to just externalize it - lots of options there with extensive security and management parameters - ssh, stunnel, spiped, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had got it working by adding:

```
appender.smswebstart.protocol = TCP
appender.smswebstart.ssl.type = SSL
appender.smswebstart.ssl.protocol = SSL
appender.smswebstart.ssl.keystore.type=KeyStore
appender.smswebstart.ssl.keystore.location=${ctx:location}
appender.smswebstart.ssl.keystore.password=${ctx:password}
appender.smswebstart.ssl.truststore.type=TrustStore
appender.smswebstart.ssl.truststore.location=${ctx:location}
appender.smswebstart.ssl.truststore.password=${ctx:password}
```

The problem with this is that it makes the store key to be in plain text here.
So, another way is to have a custom appender.

Here is how I got the custom appender.

```
@Plugin(
    name = "SSLSocket",
    category = "Core",
    elementType = "appender",
    printObject = true
)
public class SSLSocketAppender extends SocketAppender {

private static StatusLogger statusLogger = StatusLogger.getLogger();

protected SSLSocketAppender(String name, Layout<? extends Serializable> layout, Filter filter, AbstractSocketManager manager, boolean ignoreExceptions, boolean immediateFlush, Advertiser advertiser) {
    super(name, layout, filter, manager, ignoreExceptions, immediateFlush, advertiser);
}

    @PluginFactory
    public static SSLSocketAppender createAppender(@PluginAttribute("host") String host, @PluginAttribute(value = "port", defaultInt = 0) int port, @PluginAttribute("protocol") Protocol protocol, @PluginAttribute("name") String name, @PluginElement("Layout") Layout<? extends Serializable> layout, @PluginElement("Filter") Filter filter, @PluginAttribute(value = "connectTimeoutMillis",defaultInt = 0) int connectTimeoutMillis, @PluginAliases({"reconnectionDelay"}) @PluginAttribute(value = "reconnectionDelayMillis",defaultInt = 0) int reconnectDelayMillis, @PluginAttribute(value = "immediateFail",defaultBoolean = true) boolean immediateFail) {

    AbstractSocketManager manager = SslSocketManager.getSocketManager(getSSLConfig(), host, port, connectTimeoutMillis, reconnectDelayMillis, immediateFail, layout);
    return new SSLSocketAppender(name, layout, filter, manager, true, true, null);
}

    private static SslConfiguration getSSLConfig() {

    KeyStoreConfiguration keyStoreConfig = null;
    TrustStoreConfiguration trustStoreConfig = null;
    try {
        keyStoreConfig = KeyStoreConfiguration.createKeyStoreConfiguration(keyStorePath, keyStoreKey.toString(), keyFormat, null);
        trustStoreConfig = TrustStoreConfiguration.createKeyStoreConfiguration(keyStorePath, keyStoreKey.toString(), keyFormat, null);
    }
    catch (StoreConfigurationException sce)
    {
        statusLogger.log(Level.ERROR, "Unable to configure secure socket : " + sce.getMessage());
    }
        SslConfiguration sslConfig = SslConfiguration.createSSLConfiguration(Protocol.SSL.toString(),keyStoreConfig, trustStoreConfig);
        return sslConfig;
    }
}
```

and used the "SSLSocket" as the appender type instead of "Socket" in the configuration